# What happened to GNUHAWK?

Tags: redhawksdr

I'm new to REDHAWK and I noticed that with REDHAWK 1.10 that GNUHAWK seems to be all but gone.  Does anyone know any information about what happened to the it.  It looks like it could be a really useful tool.  And if it's only available on older versions I could you point me to a guide I haven't been able to find an installation guide for 1.9 either...

Answer (score 0):

You can clone GNUHAWK from here and add it to your system: https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/integration-gnuhawk

Comment: How do you add it to your system?

Comment: After you clone the project: $git clone https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/integration-gnuhawk.git

You can cd into the folder and pick which components you would like to add. It seems like some of this stuff if directly integrated into 
RH 1.10.

For adding components:
https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/integration-gnuhawk/blob/master/components/README.txt

For adding gnuradio:
https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/integration-gnuhawk/blob/master/gnuradio/README

Answer (score 0):

The REDHAWK 1.9 distribution includes RPMs for GnuHawk. You can install them as you would any other RPM file. To find the RPM you need, go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/redhawksdr/files/redhawk/ and drill down for REDAWK 1.9.0 and your desired platform.

You may also want to check out the build instructions here: https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/integration-gnuhawk/tree/develop-1.9